# Rename package name in android 3.0

Tags: android, package

I have read almost 10-12 answer on how to change package name but every answer failed to do his job. There are errors after renaming the packages like the old imports are presents.

ex: suppose the old package was com.example.x after changing I made it in.ex.x but in every class file the old imports are present, such as com.example.x.something.

How to rename packages without error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, if you want to change com.example.x to  in.ex.x --->

- In your Project pane, click on the little **Gears icon**
- Uncheck / De-select the **Compact Empty Middle Packages** option
- Your package directory will now be broken up in individual directories
- Individually select each directory you want to rename, and:

  ```
   1) Right-click it
   2) Select **Refactor**
   3) Click on **Rename**
   4) In the Pop-up dialog, click on **Rename Package** instead of Rename Directory
   5) Enter the new name and hit **Refactor**
   6) Click **Do Refactor** in the bottom
   7) Allow a minute to let Android Studio update all changes
  ```

> **Note:** When renaming com in Android Studio, it might give a
>   warning. In such case, select **Rename All**

- Now open your **Gradle Build File** (`build.gradle` - Usually `app` or `mobile`). Update the `applicationId` to your new Package Name and Sync Gradle, if it hasn't already been updated automatically:
- You may need to change the `package=` attribute in your manifest.
- Clean and Rebuild.

Comment: In the fourth step I see only two options Rename Current and Rename All

Comment: What if you want to rename com.example.x to example.x? Basically removed 1 layer of directory?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this (assuming you're using Android Studio) :

- open Manifest
- right click on the package name instead the application tag > Refactor
- select to refactor the package name
- set a new package name
- validate the modifications

That is.

Comment: yes after that I came across two options <b>Rename All</b> and <b>Rename Currenet</b> tried both of them but none worked.

Comment: I look at the Manifest, the package name is in manifest tag itself and not in application tag? Can you still refactor?

Answer (score 0):

In your Project pane, click on the settings icon

Select / De-select the Empty Middle Packages option

Your package directory will be individual directories

Right click -> refactor -> rename -> Rename the package.

Comment: did the same but it create another package with the new name specified and does not delete the old package also it does not change content (imports) in each class file

Comment: refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package

Answer (score 0):

First you need to edit the package name in build.gradle (app)

```
applicationId "com.myapplication"
```

Open the **TODO** tab in the toolbar under the IDE (Android Sdtudo) it includes Android Profiler, Logcat, v.v...
Then you can right click on the name of the package you want to change, select **Refactor-> Rename**, after entering the new name you can click on Refactor button and see below tab TODO 2 button **Refactor** and **Cancel**. Click **Do Refactor** you will see it change successfully.

Comment: In the TODO tab, I can see the package on right-clicking the package gives me only one option "Jump to Source"

Answer (score 0):

you can change package name from left side ProjectView

-> select your package name by clicking
-> press shift+F6 and select Rename Package   [Check this image it might help you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2l9C.png)